# cassandra: create supercolumn using Perl

Tags: perl, cassandra

In Cassandra 1.0 the Thrift interface doesn't support batch_insert anymore. What's the current method to insert a supercolumn via perl?

Comment: You probably don't want to see me link this library again, but this one does support inserting supercolumns: http://fmgoncalves.github.com/p5-cassandra-simple/#insert_super .  At the least, you could look at how that's implemented.

Comment: @TylerHobbs - no worries! Tips are always appreciated. I did manage to get super columns inserted using the batch_mutate cmd. Now to retrieve the data.. *sigh*..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

batch_mutate replaced batch_insert in 0.7.

Comment: Is this function available via Perl? Or do I need to get my hands dirty with Thrift? (Is Perl really supported - do I need to move to Java for this sort of work?)

Comment: That's the thrift method name...  if you were using batch_insert before you should be able to use batch_mutate now.

That said, there isn't a really good high-level Perl client out there that I know of.  IMO the best client for any language is Pycassa (Python).

Comment: I got this to work using batch_mutate. Unfortunately im running into many problems with slicing by time range. Cassandra might be close to being abandoned.